# Linear independence of a matrix with only variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-independence

I am really struggling with the following problem since it has no numbers to find a determinate, I am not sure how to solve/prove this.

The question: Let a,b,c in R^3 be linearly independent. Show that {a+b+c, a-b-c, a} is linearly independent. Is the same true for {a+b, a+c, c-b}

So far I have tried putting the matrix in Ax=b form setting it equal to zero and simplifying the matrix by elimination, really I can't tell if I am overthinking, or underthinking the problem, but for whatever reason I can't make sense of it.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In your question, do you mean that $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^3$ rather than $\mathbb R^2$? Any three vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ will necessarily be linearly dependent, so asking for  $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^2$ which are linearly independent is problematic!

Comment: Also, do you really mean $a-b-b$, or is that a typo for something else? And is the b in a,b,c the same as the b in Ax=b? If not, it's a bad idea to use the same letter for two different things in one question – better do some editing!

Comment: Edited. Yes R will have 3 dimensions here, I was not paying attention. However, in the specific problem, R is defined as R^n. Although I understand how to solve a standard matrix, I have no idea how to use proofs to solve a matrix such as this which is assumed to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea for this exercise is that the linear independence of vectors does not depend on the choice of basis. SInce $a$, $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent, you can take them to be a new basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you now express the vectors $\{a+b+c,a-b-c,a\}$ in this new basis, you obtain the vectors:
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\},
$$
for which you can check linear independence in the usual way. A similar approach can be used to check if $\{a+b,a+c,b-c\}$ are linearly independent or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind but I kept telling myself it was a bad idea. My professor is very bad at explaining things but to me this method just makes sense, the matrix results in a determinant of zero, meaning it is not linearly independent. I am now positive my professor also wrote the question incorrectly because this system cannot be L.I.